# Convert _body content (string) to an arrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, filereader

I have an Ionic application which downloads a file from a Web API. The content of the file can be found in the `_body` property of the HTTP response.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is convert this text into an `arrayBuffer` so I can save the content into a file.

However, the issue that I'm having is that any file (PDF files in my instance) that have images and/or large in size either don't show up at all or show up as correputed files.

At first I thought this was an issue relating Ionic. So to make sure I tried to simulate this issue and I was able to reproduce it.
Is this snippet you can select a PDF file, then download it. You would find that the downloaded file is corrupted and exactly how my Ionic app displays them.

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file_input" class="foo" />
<div id="output_field" class="foo"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#file_input').on('change', function(e){
        readFile(this.files[0], function(e) {
            //manipulate with result...
            $('#output_field').text(e.target.result);
            try {
            var file = new Blob([e.target.result], { type: 'application/pdf;base64' });
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
            var seconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
            var fileName = "cert" + parseInt(seconds) + ".pdf";
            var a = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(a);
            a.style = "display: none";
            a.href = fileURL;
            a.download = fileName;
            a.click();
            }
            catch (err){
            $('#output_field').text(err);
            }
        });

    });
});

function readFile(file, callback){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    //reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/68qeau3h/3/

Now, when using `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);` everything works as expected, however in my particular case, I used `reader.readAsText(file);` because this is how the data is retrieve for me, this is text form.

When adding these lines of code to try to convert the string into an arrayBuffer

```
...
var buf = new ArrayBuffer(e.target.result.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
             var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
             for (var i=0, strLen=e.target.result.length; i<strLen; i++) {
               bufView[i] = e.target.result.charCodeAt(i);
                  }

            var file = new Blob([buf], { type: 'application/pdf' });
...
```

This will not work and generate PDF files that the browser can't open.

So to recap, what I'm trying to do is somehow convert the result I get from `reader.readAsText(file);` to what `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);` produces. Because the files I'm working with, or the data im retrieving from my backend is this text form.

Comment: You should use `readAsArrayBuffer` if it's working... It's not clear why you're making things harder on yourself...

Comment: Because, like I said, this was only to simulate my issue. The file im reciving is just like what reader.readAsText(file); outputs.

Comment: `readAsArrayBuffer` doesn't "care" that what you're receiving is text; it will convert whatever is in the file to an `ArrayBuffer`, whether it's binary, ASCII, UTF, or EBCDIC.